# Rails: update_attribut wihout validation - like object.save(false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I trying to update a model on a callback but the validation is causing some havic and I'm controller the material getting saved so I'm looking for  way to do update attributes without a validation and I would like to keep it on the update method not on validations for example :conditions =>

Something like this?

```
easy_address.update_attributes(some_attributes)(false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that is:

```
easy_address.update_attributes_without_validation(some_attributes) # o_0
```

I might be wrong. If it does not work try:

```
easy_address.send(:attributes=, some_attributes)
easy_address.save(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't find a way to update_attributes without raising validations.